# 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element

Tags: android, build, androidx

I have issue when i add implementation  'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0' 
warning suggest to me

```
'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-123:19 to override.
```

**This is my Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.together">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <!-- 맵 이용하기 위함 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- 다음 지도 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- 대략적인 위치 참조 권한 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <!-- 정확한 위치 참조 권한 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

but when i change

```
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

this to

```
'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

with this 
the new error show and suggetion to me

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(whateverString) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-53
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-123:19 to override.
```

That suggest change android:appComponentFactory this

What should i do if i want to implementation it?

**This is my Module: app**
+ I add my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blogapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'//
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3' //있고 ㅇㅇ


    //Expandable 프래그먼트 goodbyepet selectmenu
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablecheckrecyclerview:1.4'


    //유튜브 강의 3 추가함
    //1장에서 설정한거 추가


    //1장에서 설정한거 추가
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    //유튜브 강의 3 추가함


    // firebase core

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'

    // firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'

    // firebase storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'

    // firebase realtime database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

    implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4"


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //photo control
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

    // card view
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    // swipe cards for petching
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'    //있고 ㅇㅇ
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'   //있고 ㅇㅇ
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'  //있고 ㅇㅇ

    // Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    // circle design
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    // rectangle design
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'

    // bumptech/glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    //picaso/glide
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // Edit Text
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    // lombok 사용
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'

    // User Map
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'

    implementation 'noman.placesapi:placesAPI:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablecheckrecyclerview:1.4'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'


    //Calendar

    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1'


    // LifeCycle online or offline 여부 판별
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    // retrofit2 통신 라이브러리
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    //calendar view
    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.5.0'


    // Searchable Spinner



}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my projed build**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // radio button
        classpath 'lib.kingja.switchbutton:switchbutton:1.1.8'
        classpath 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: I assume that you are using `androidx dependencies` in your project, while the lib `com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0` is using `com.android.support:appcompat`  you can not use both `androidx dependencies` and  `com.android.support:appcompat` togather

Comment: @ZohaibAmir i added my build.gradle

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes you are right now i'm use androidx

Comment: @hirose was the issue fixed?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir No.. i think there is no way to use maybe? Nilesh said that lib can't using in androidx

Comment: @NileshRathod so then... there is no way to using that lib ? if i using androidx?

Comment: @Hirose check my answer

Answer (score 1):

After `android:allowBackup="false"` add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"`.
use this code in **mainfest** file do close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you are using a third party library that depends on support library and you are using AndroidX in your project. This can be fixed using Jetifier:

Go to your **`gradle.properties`** file and add this line:

`android.enableJetifier=true`

> **android.enableJetifier:** When set to true, this flag indicates that you want to have tool support (from the Android Gradle plugin) to automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were written for AndroidX. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to false.

If this still causes error, please use `Migrate to AndroidX` from Refactor menu, it should automatically fix this.

[image]

Comment: i already added that code in my gradle.properties but it's same issue show to me

Comment: @Hirose use the Migrate to AndroidX button

Comment: ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-36
 is also present at [com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-123:19 to override.

Comment: @Hirose complete remove `allowBackup` and `replace` then try to migrate again

Comment: you mean just leave  'tools:"android:"' like this??

Comment: @Hirose I mean remove both these attributes temporarily, so remove **`android:allowBackup="false"`** and **`tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`**

Comment: After i delete it and i run Migrate to AndroidX but 
still don't working 
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from [noman.placesapi:placesAPI:1.1.3] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-36
 is also present at [com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-122:19 to override.
same issue show to me

Comment: @Hirose try removing depenency `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` temporarily and if it migrates successfully then place it back

Comment: @Hirose also, I would suggest that you use official Google Places library as this library hasn't been updated in over 3 years

Comment: but that library like that is not exist in Goolge Places libarary

Comment: @Hirose use the rest api for google places, it has these functions you are looking for. The library that you are using is also using the rest api

Comment: I don't understand, the library like that is made by private right? so like that i can't find like searchable spinner from Goolge Places libarary